# Width of div does not fit to screen after a certain width of the browser (Responsiveness)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my website responsive. But I can't seem to make my div's responsive.
Past a certain point a gap at the side will be made.
Width 100% does not work, it seems as if the only way to make it touch the end of the screen is by increasing the percentage of width.

[This is what it looks like past screen width of 596px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQqdE.png)

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It would have been easier if you put minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://us.123rf.com/450wm/imichman/imichman1809/imichman180900055/109243437-.jpg?ver=6');
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: #ffafafdd;
  border: 5px solid #dd0d0d;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: justify;
}

/* width */
#cover::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Track */
#cover::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Handle */
#cover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ff000099;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='cover'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sit amet ligula ullamcorper, lacinia elit sit amet, viverra massa. Duis mauris urna, ornare molestie imperdiet eget, finibus a diam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla sed lacus ex. Aliquam ut semper tortor, ut fringilla nibh. Curabitur vel mauris eu neque accumsan dictum non ut tortor. Fusce sed felis euismod, molestie diam a, convallis nisl. Praesent ac augue sagittis, tincidunt lectus eu, viverra justo. Nam nunc tortor, posuere non tincidunt quis, porta venenatis augue. Morbi nec felis sodales, suscipit dolor ac, accumsan erat. Sed nibh ex, ullamcorper vel erat eget, scelerisque luctus augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Praesent semper convallis justo eu efficitur. Proin in porta felis, sed porttitor lectus.

  Donec luctus nisl ac metus lacinia sollicitudin. Vivamus facilisis ultrices odio ut vestibulum. Curabitur viverra, ante eu rhoncus porttitor, nulla nisi elementum magna, ac finibus dui sapien eget elit. Aenean lacinia risus id dolor suscipit maximus. Vivamus vulputate porttitor arcu at volutpat. Sed pretium dignissim lectus, vel facilisis tortor ultrices id. Donec nec sem eu ante cursus malesuada. Donec felis eros, suscipit ac condimentum sed, tincidunt sed augue. Donec lacinia vel augue id tempor. Suspendisse faucibus ullamcorper magna, sit amet sollicitudin nibh sagittis venenatis. In ex eros, tincidunt nec ligula a, faucibus dictum elit. Donec congue mi lectus, eget blandit leo consequat mollis. Cras vestibulum congue sodales. Nullam sit amet auctor ligula, at dignissim sapien. Praesent cursus libero quis feugiat laoreet. In tincidunt enim arcu, id euismod libero volutpat ac.

  Vestibulum rhoncus ante laoreet venenatis sollicitudin. Aliquam a consequat lectus. Aenean sit amet odio tempus, posuere velit et, vehicula ipsum. Sed auctor ex risus, quis accumsan ligula fringilla ac. Aliquam non eros tellus. Vivamus convallis, justo nec vehicula feugiat, tellus purus rhoncus lectus, nec ullamcorper neque augue ut sem. Phasellus ultricies velit a neque hendrerit vulputate. Nunc felis purus, suscipit ac lectus vitae, tincidunt porta eros. Sed maximus orci ac odio pharetra sodales. Quisque et pulvinar ex. Praesent suscipit, erat a blandit dictum, ligula dui imperdiet mauris, sed tincidunt nibh quam id lacus. Donec libero velit, ultricies sagittis viverra ut, consectetur imperdiet dui. Integer fringilla, purus sed facilisis porttitor, est neque posuere nisi, at aliquam dui dui sed odio. Cras consectetur condimentum ullamcorper.
</div>
```